# Redirect URL using country IP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two commerce websites, `example.com` and `example.ca`. What we would like is to set up redirects:

1. If a non-Canadian visitor goes to `example.ca` they get directed to `example.com`
2. If a Canadian visitor goes to `example.com`, they get directed to `example.ca`

Comment: Please don't, that's probably the most annoying feature in the modern Internet, you're re-directed to somewhere you didn't want to go ...

Comment: you should just give a popup for user to go to either .com or .ca

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to server side geoIp solution, depending on language you use. However you can use javascript to redirect which is not the best solution. Here is the code that can be used for javascript.

```
function getCountryCode(callback){
//i am assuming you are using jQuery for ajax
jQuery.getJSON("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
  callback(data.country_code);
    });
}
```

now you can redirect based one country code. for example

```
getCountryCode(function(country){
         //for canada store 
            if (country=='CA'){ 


             }
            else {
                  window.location.href =='' //US Store  
                }
          });
```

This is just an idea you can use, however you need to consider the default store for people outside US an Canada. As i told you before sever side redirection will be better. Also you also need to give  token in **url** that stop redirection. For example if you are in Canada and need to see a store, in that case you can use cookie which stop redirection for period of time.  I hope this will give you bit more information about your problem.

Comment: https://freegeoip.net/json/  this API has been close down please use alternative API url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [geoPlugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/examples)

Just add:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and you can use geoplugin_countryCode() function to get the country code.